# How to navigate to a different page in phone sdk 8.1 (xaml c#) using a timer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I managed to get into learning how to make phone apps. I'm completely new to c# and xaml. But I have done visual basic to a basic knowledge.

I am trying to recreate my project in the windows phone and I've got the basic progress bar in a timer but when the timer has reached it's end I want it to navigate to a new page which I have created. I have seen many different examples but none have helped It either doesn't work or has an error.

This is the code so far on the MainPage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using ProgramOSMobile.Resources;

namespace ProgramOSMobile
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        private DispatcherTimer timer;
        private int i, j;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += timer_tick;
            Init();
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            j = i = Convert.ToInt32(3);
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i);
        }

        private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
            i = i + j;
            if (i == 1010)
            {

                timer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This all works, but when it comes to using this code for example:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LoginScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Or indeed this new one for the Phone 8.1:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginScreen));
```

I get an error on the 'Frame' part.

Sorry for the really long question but it's just really confusing me.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are using Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project and error you are having is used in WinRT version. Here is code for navigation after timer.

for WinRT
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

```
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300) };
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += ((ax, by) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Loader.IsActive = false;


            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
        });
    }
```

and **for Silverlight project which you are using**

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded+=MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            timer.Start();
            timer.Tick += ((ax, by) => { timer.Stop();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Source Code/Recieve.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            });            
        }
```

You are using Init method for initialization of timer and you can do it fixed I did or dynamic as you like. If any error is thrown then check exception in output it maybe because of Xaml error on next page i.e. HomePage. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still getting errors. I have attached a link which contains an image just so you can see what is errored. Thanks Dan: [Top of code](http://imgur.com/mqioDAp) --- [Bottom Part of code](http://imgur.com/slGm0zF) {The code has been changed since then but not too much different!}

Comment: I have seen your code and you are using Silverlight WP8.1 project and I have added code for that. I have put code for WinRT also.

Comment: Thank you so much, I left the code how it was and just added this to the `timer_tick`: `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LoginScreen.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));` (I know you changed it all but that code is all I needed and it works fine.) Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me .. Try it out

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using ProgramOSMobile.Resources;

namespace ProgramOSMobile
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int tick=0;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
            timer.Start();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(splash);
        }

        private void splash(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tick++;

            if(tick==5){
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The above code has a timer interval of 0.5 seconds and time tick rate of 1